# Impedance matching using transformer vs other circuits, what is the difference

Tags: transistors, transformer, impedance-matching

We can use transformers to carry out impedance matching. However, using various configurations of  BJT circuit can achieve the same effect. Here I am talking about common collector, common base and common emmiter configurations. In different configurations we get different input output impedances that can be controlled to much extent.

When do we use a transformer to match impedances and when do we use other circuitry. I understand that if we have very high power applications than transofmer can provide isolation, but what about other not so high voltage applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a transformer when I want to isolate one signal from another. The transformer provides galvanic separation between two circuits and this is needed in several applications. One that springs to mind is a data coupler between a rotating machine and a static data receiver - you can't use wires but, you can use a rotating transformer to couple the data.

I've used near-field data transfer of modulated data as well and, in effect, antennas have become a transformer.

You can find RS485 chips that now embody isolation transformers and, ADI have a series of data coupling chips that incorporate tiny transformers to provide galvanic isolation.

Comment: OK, so when do we use the BJT to do this? What I understand is that now we try to use transformer at most places. Is this true? What about other ways to match impedance? When are they used?

Comment: @quantum231 Impedance matching is done using a resistor or network of R, L and C - the BJT or transformer is an "aide" and sometimes a hindrance to matching impedances but it's the resistor/network that does the Z matching. It is done to avoid data reflections corrupting data or at an RF level to maximize power throughput.

Comment: I have heard/read about using transformers and BJTs being used for impedance matching but not passive components like R,L,C. I am not sure what you are referring to here. You might be referring to high speed digital or RF where we use termination resistors. I know about that though this question is not related to that.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide a link to what you have heard/read?