# Why does FZT653 a SMT BJT device have 2 collectors?

Tags: bjt

The FZT653 in SOT223 package has 3 normal terminals at the bottom, collector, emitter, base. However, it also has a collector on the top. Why is this so? Which is the real collector.

Comment: What do you mean with "real"? They are both the collector, use whichever you want

Comment: So either could be used but not both. Why does mankind need a bjt package that had two possible collectors, one bigger than the other and both pointing in opposite directions?

Comment: What defines a "normal" connection?

Comment: Were these questions answered to your satisfaction: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100141/why-do-we-need-many-complex-voltage-references-when-a-zener-can-do-the-job? What about this one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108214/impedance-matching-using-transformer-vs-other-circuits-what-is-the-difference? It's a small price to pay for good advice and you have plenty of questions raised that you haven't "accepted". There were just two that I remember.

Comment: Dear Andy, all of my questions are answered to satisfaction on this forum. Particularly the answers given by you, sephro, olin and martin are the best. I will be careful that I always accept an answer by clicking on the tick from here on.

Comment: Normal connection is what is to be used by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both collectors are connected together inside the package. The one on the "top" (or tab) is normally soldered down to a an area of copper on the PCB to act as a heat sink. To achieve the maximum rating for this transistor (3W power dissipation) this copper pad needs to be about 50mm x 50mm (see the datasheet).

In practice you should connect both collectors together in your circuit.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The above can only realistically mean that C=C i.e. two connections to the same place.